# Is there a file size limit to the Scala templates?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a scala template that contains embedded hard coded images 
(eg <img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0K... ). For testing I used the same image.

When I compile the application I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 106 at 119
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1044)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:984)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:125)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:770)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:114)
    at javassist.CtClassType.<init>(CtClassType.java:95)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:728)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:706)
    at play.core.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.rewriteAccess(PropertiesEnhancer.java:145)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(PlayCommands.scala:327)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(PlayCommands.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:327)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:305)
....
```

However, no error was thrown when compiling with only 1 embedded image.

So I'm assuming it has to do with the file size.

Is there scala template file size setting and if so how to increase it? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks.

Comment: How big is the template file?  At one point we ran into a issue because our conf.routes grew to >64kiB and was being handled as a single method (the JVM has a hard-limit on method size of 64kiB).  I'm not an expert on the template engine, but looking through my .template.scala files it looks like you could be experiencing a related issue.

Comment: Something related just got bumped up on the mailing list, if the root cause turns out to be the template file size, there has been confirmation of this behavior by other users: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/wC-do6-JO5s/nigH17VofCUJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the templates are reduced to methods by the engine, and the methods are being compiled and run on the jvm there is a hard limit of 64 kiB for any method.  The templates can be slightly larger than that in practice, but the largest single method may not exceed the limit.

If you want to see the output of the template engine to inspect the methods for yourself, after the project has been compiled they can be found at `<project>\target\scala-2.10\src_managed\main\views\html\...`

More details:

- [Confirmation of similar behaviour on Play! Framework mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/wC-do6-JO5s/nigH17VofCUJ)
- [JVM Method size limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9)

Comment: That must be it. The template that has the problem is 971 kb. I worked around it by embedding the image at runtime.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to break down your template to smaller parts. It would not only help to avoid this issue, but it may also make the template easier to understand and maintain.