# unexcepted exception-IOException:invalid constant type 117 at 283

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

[image: unexpected exception]

i am running a scala project in play famework 2.2, but not running.it was running earlier, suddenly today it getting this exception.

edit:

```
java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 117 at 283
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1236)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1167)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:175)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:777)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:118)
    at javassist.CtClassType.<init>(CtClassType.java:96)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:728)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:706)
    at play.core.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.rewriteAccess(PropertiesEnhancer.java:145)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:91)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 117 at 283
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1236)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1167)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:175)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:777)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:118)
    at javassist.CtClassType.<init>(CtClassType.java:96)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:728)
    at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:706)
    at play.core.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.rewriteAccess(PropertiesEnhancer.java:145)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:113)
    at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:91)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (compile:compile) java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 117 at 283
```

Comment: i tried  play clean update,
play compile run,
but nothing works

Comment: i run another project that runs perfectly, but this projects not running

Comment: When you show an exception on StackOverflow, please copy and paste it, do not use a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error before. For me, it meant that you might have a Scala template file that is too big.

Take a look at this similar issue : [Is there a file size limit to the Scala templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500073/is-there-a-file-size-limit-to-the-scala-templates)